# HTML Checkbox/Radio button design issue

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

I want to design my Radio buttons. The code I am using is as below :

```
<form action="#">
  <input type="radio" id="yes" name="fav_language" value="Yes">
  <label for="yes">Yes</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="no" name="fav_language" value="No">
  <label for="no">No</label><br>

</form>
```

I want to design it as below image. I dont know how i can do this.  have searched in google but didn't find any appropiate solution. Can anyone help me with this ?

image link :
https://202.40.184.227/websites/image.jpeg

[image]

Comment: I dont think that can be achieved with pure CSS if you are open to using to JS you can do that.

Comment: If you are asking about that double outlines, you can achieve that by using css property `border` and `outline`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.container .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<label class="container">Yes
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">No
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```